# In Exoplayer,How to reload and resume playback automatically?

Tags: android, video, exoplayer

I"m streaming HLS video with EXOPlayer and it is working perfectly. However, If there is some changes with HLS streaming source video and then video playing stopped and keep showing loading circle.
My question is how could I force reload and resume playback for realtime when video stopped? Here is my code

```
public class TvPlay extends AppCompatActivity implements HlsSampleSource.EventListener, View.OnClickListener {


public static final int RENDERER_COUNT = 2;
public static final int TYPE_AUDIO = 1;
private ExoPlayer player;
private SurfaceView surface;
private Handler mainHandler;
private TrackRenderer videoRenderer;
private LinearLayout root;
public static final int TYPE_VIDEO = 0;
private View decorView;
private int uiImmersiveOptions;
private RelativeLayout loadingPanel;
private Runnable updatePlayer, hideControls;

//Implementing current time, total time and seekbar
private TextView txt_ct, txt_td;
private SeekBar seekBar;
private PlayerControl playerControl;

public enum ControlsMode {
    FULLCONTORLS
}

private ControlsMode controlsState;

private ImageButton btn_play;
private ImageButton btn_pause;
private ImageButton btn_settings;
private String url;

{
    updatePlayer = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            switch (player.getPlaybackState()) {
                case ExoPlayer.STATE_BUFFERING:
                    loadingPanel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    break;
                case ExoPlayer.STATE_ENDED:
                    finish();
                    break;
                case ExoPlayer.STATE_IDLE:
                    loadingPanel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    break;
                case ExoPlayer.STATE_PREPARING:
                    loadingPanel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    break;
                case ExoPlayer.STATE_READY:
                    loadingPanel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

            String totDur = String.format("%02d.%02d.%02d",
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(player.getDuration()),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(player.getDuration()) -
                            TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(player.getDuration())), // The change is in this line
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(player.getDuration()) -
                            TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(player.getDuration())));
            String curDur = String.format("%02d.%02d.%02d",
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(player.getCurrentPosition()),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(player.getCurrentPosition()) -
                            TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(player.getCurrentPosition())), // The change is in this line
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(player.getCurrentPosition()) -
                            TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(player.getCurrentPosition())));
            txt_ct.setText(curDur);
            txt_td.setText(totDur);
            seekBar.setMax((int) player.getDuration());
            seekBar.setProgress((int) player.getCurrentPosition());

            mainHandler.postDelayed(updatePlayer, 200);
        }
    };
}

{
    hideControls = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            hideAllControls();
        }
    };
}

private void hideAllControls() {
    if (controlsState == ControlsMode.FULLCONTORLS) {
        if (root.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
            root.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiImmersiveOptions);
}

private void showControls() {
    if (controlsState == ControlsMode.FULLCONTORLS) {
        if (root.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
            root.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
    mainHandler.removeCallbacks(hideControls);
    mainHandler.postDelayed(hideControls, 5000);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            showControls();
            break;
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tvplay);
    url=getIntent().getStringExtra("url");
    DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);

    uiImmersiveOptions = (View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
    );
    decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiImmersiveOptions);

    loadingPanel = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.loadingVPanel);
    txt_ct = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_currentTime);
    txt_td = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_totalDuration);
    seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekbar);
    seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            player.seekTo(seekBar.getProgress());
        }
    });

    btn_play = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_play);
    btn_pause = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_pause);
    btn_settings = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_settings);

    btn_play.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn_pause.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn_settings.setOnClickListener(this);
    root = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.root);
    root.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    surface = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surface_view);
    mainHandler = new Handler();
    execute();


}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int i1 = v.getId();
    if (i1 == R.id.btn_pause) {
        if (playerControl.isPlaying()) {
            playerControl.pause();
            btn_pause.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            btn_play.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
    if (i1 == R.id.btn_play) {
        if (!playerControl.isPlaying()) {
            playerControl.start();
            btn_pause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            btn_play.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
    if (i1 == R.id.btn_settings) {
        PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(TvPlay.this, v);
        popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                player.setSelectedTrack(0, (item.getItemId() - 1));
                return false;
            }
        });
        Menu menu = popup.getMenu();
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, 0, 0, "Video Quality");
        for (int i = 0; i < player.getTrackCount(0); i++) {
            MediaFormat format = player.getTrackFormat(0, i);
            if (MimeTypes.isVideo(format.mimeType)) {
                if (format.adaptive) {
                    menu.add(1, (i + 1), (i + 1), "Auto");
                } else {
                    menu.add(1, (i + 1), (i + 1), format.bitrate/1000 + " kbps");
                }
            }
        }
        menu.setGroupCheckable(1, true, true);
        menu.findItem((player.getSelectedTrack(0) + 1)).setChecked(true);
        popup.show();
    }
}

private void execute() {
    player = ExoPlayer.Factory.newInstance(RENDERER_COUNT);
    playerControl = new PlayerControl(player);
    if (player != null) {
        HpLib_RendererBuilder hpLibRendererBuilder = getHpLibRendererBuilder();
        hpLibRendererBuilder.buildRenderers(this);
        loadingPanel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mainHandler.postDelayed(updatePlayer, 200);
        mainHandler.postDelayed(hideControls, 3000);
        controlsState = ControlsMode.FULLCONTORLS;
    }
}

private HpLib_RendererBuilder getHpLibRendererBuilder() {
    String userAgent = Util.getUserAgent(this, "AndroidLiveTV");
    if(url.endsWith(".m3u8")){
        return new HpLib_HlsHpLibRendererBuilder(this, userAgent, url);
    }else{
        return new HpLib_ExtractorHpLibRendererBuilder(this, userAgent, Uri.parse(url));
    }


/*    
switch (video_type[currentTrackIndex]) {
case "hls":
return new HpLib_HlsHpLibRendererBuilder(this, userAgent, video_url[currentTrackIndex]);

case "others":
return new HpLib_ExtractorHpLibRendererBuilder(this, userAgent, Uri.parse(video_url[currentTrackIndex]));
default:
throw new IllegalStateException("Unsupported type: " + video_url[currentTrackIndex]);
} 
*/

}

Handler getMainHandler() {
    return mainHandler;
}

void onRenderersError(Exception e) {
}

void onRenderers(TrackRenderer[] renderers, BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter) {
    for (int i = 0; i < renderers.length; i++) {
        if (renderers[i] == null) {
            renderers[i] = new DummyTrackRenderer();
        }
    }
    // Complete preparation.
    this.videoRenderer = renderers[TYPE_VIDEO];
    pushSurface(false);
    player.prepare(renderers);
    player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
}

private void pushSurface(boolean blockForSurfacePush) {
    if (videoRenderer == null) {
        return;
    }
    if (blockForSurfacePush) {
        player.blockingSendMessage(
                videoRenderer, MediaCodecVideoTrackRenderer.MSG_SET_SURFACE, surface.getHolder().getSurface());
    } else {
        player.sendMessage(
                videoRenderer, MediaCodecVideoTrackRenderer.MSG_SET_SURFACE, surface.getHolder().getSurface());
    }
}

private void killPlayer() {
    if (player != null) {
        player.release();
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    killPlayer();
}

@Override
public void onLoadStarted(int sourceId, long length, int type, int trigger, Format format, long mediaStartTimeMs, long mediaEndTimeMs) {

}

@Override
public void onLoadCompleted(int sourceId, long bytesLoaded, int type, int trigger, Format format, long mediaStartTimeMs, long mediaEndTimeMs, long elapsedRealtimeMs, long loadDurationMs) {

}

@Override
public void onLoadCanceled(int sourceId, long bytesLoaded) {

}

@Override
public void onLoadError(int sourceId, IOException e) {

}

@Override
public void onUpstreamDiscarded(int sourceId, long mediaStartTimeMs, long mediaEndTimeMs) {

}

@Override
public void onDownstreamFormatChanged(int sourceId, Format format, int trigger, long mediaTimeMs) {

}
```